# Add custom path on specific key press after git command in Git bash

Tags: bash, cmd.exe, git, git-bash

I am looking to reduce the repetitive work.
Following is the example,
currently, I am using frequently the following command and I want to custom set the directory.
I.e git add /pkg/XYZ/123/456/789/frontend/templet/xyz.html
So, When I write git add and press the shortcut key, fills the path /pkg/XYZ/123/456/789/frontend/templet/
like git add /pkg/XYZ/123/456/789/frontend/templet/  and then I could write the file name.

Answer (score 0):

just write a batch/bash script to do it for you.

Batch:
@echo off

```
set arg1=%1

git add /pkg/XYZ/123/456/789/frontend/templet/%arg1%
```

`arg1` is the first argument passed after the program in the command line.

So if you save this file as "gitTemplate.bat" or something, you could run it as:

```
`gitTemplate [name-of-file]`
```

And the batch script would run it as:

```
`git add /pkg/XYZ/123/456/789/frontend/templet/[name-of-file]`
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

git add /pkg/XYZ/123/456/789/frontend/templet/$1
```

'$1' is is the first argument passed after the program in the command line.

So if you save this file as "gitTemplate.sh" or something, you could run it as:

```
./gitTemplate.sh [name-of-file]
```

And the batch script would run it as:

```
`git add /pkg/XYZ/123/456/789/frontend/templet/[name-of-file]`
```